# checkbox widget within navbar shiny

Tags: r, shiny, navbar

Is it possible to create a checkbox widget within navbar line? This is an [example](http://www.bootply.com/103995#) of what I have in mind.

The following creates a `checkboxInput`, but the interactivity does not appear to work correctly:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- navbarPage(
  "App Title",
  tabPanel("Plot"),
  navbarMenu("More",
    tabPanel("Summary"),
    tabPanel("Table")
  ),
  tabPanel(checkboxInput("chk_1", "This is a label")),
  hr(),
  fluidRow(column(3, verbatimTextOutput("value")))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
 output$value <- renderPrint({ input$chk_1 })   
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm surprised this works at all, as it uses the checkbox as the title of a `tabPanel`, and includes the `hr()` and output as elements in the `navbarPage`, not in a panel. Surprisingly, you can fix the specific updating problem simply by adding a reactive observer that updates the checkbox value. In your `server` function, you just need to add:

```
observe({
   updateCheckboxInput(session, "chk_1", value=input$chk_1)
})
```

I would also add a `value= "chk_1_panel"` or some such to the panel represented by the checkbox, so it has a rational name when selected.

Note that when you select the checkbox, it will switch to a different panel. I slightly changed your code to move the output into a panel to emphasize this panel switch. The complete example is then:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- navbarPage(
   "App Title",
   tabPanel("Plot"),
   navbarMenu( "More",
      tabPanel("Summary"),
      tabPanel("Table")
   ),
   tabPanel( value= "chk_1_panel",
      checkboxInput("chk_1", "This is a label"),
      hr(),
      fluidRow(column(3, verbatimTextOutput("value")))
   )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
   observe({
      updateCheckboxInput(session, "chk_1", value=input$chk_1)
   })
   output$value <- renderPrint({ input$chk_1 })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```