# search field in shiny navbarPage

Tags: r, twitter-bootstrap, shiny

I am trying to get a global search field into my `navbarPage` after some `tabPanel`. I am not sure if it is possible, since all my tests producing the `textInput` outside the `navbar`.

The rStudio shiny layout guide points to the [bootstrap navbar documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar) , where they actually did exactly this. But I am not able to reproduce it with my shiny app.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI(
  shiny::navbarPage('test',
    shiny::tabPanel('my app',
   fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),

  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("bins",
                  "Number of bins:",
                  min = 1,
                  max = 50,
                  value = 30)
    ),

    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("distPlot")
    )
  ))),

  ### Still inside navbarPage
  shiny::textInput("text", 
                   label=h3("Text input"), 
                   value="should be inside the navbar!")
))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({

    # generate bins based on input$bins from ui.R
    x    <- faithful[, 2]
    bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)

    # draw the histogram with the specified number of bins
    hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')

  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: This may have some insights into what you want to do http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36360146/checkbox-widget-within-navbar-shiny.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do this by manipulating the navbar HTML a little bit. Valter is correct - you can achieve this by constructing the menu entirely in HTML instead of using Shiny. But there's an easier way: you can build the navbar in regular Shiny, and then use `htmltools` to slightly modify it. Here's one quick solution that I think is the cleanest out of the current proposed solutions:

```
library(shiny)

navbarPageWithInputs <- function(..., inputs) {
  navbar <- navbarPage(...)
  form <- tags$form(class = "navbar-form", inputs)
  navbar[[3]][[1]]$children[[1]] <- htmltools::tagAppendChild(
    navbar[[3]][[1]]$children[[1]], form)
  navbar
}

ui <- navbarPageWithInputs(
  "Test app",
  tabPanel("tab1", "tab 1", textOutput("out")),
  tabPanel("tab2", "tab 2"),
  inputs = textInput("search", NULL, placeholder = "Search")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$out <- renderText(input$search)
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Basically I created a `navbarPageWithInputs()` function that accepts all the same parameters as `navbarPage()`, and also an `inputs` parameter. All this function does is call the regular `navbarPage()`, and then adds the given inputs to the HTML.

Comment: Works great when `collapsible = FALSE`. When `collapsible = TRUE` the input is not aligned with the other navbar labels. `navbar[[3]][[1]]$children[[1]]$children[[2]]` works in that case

Comment: As per the last versions of shiny, the structure of the navbar object has changed. This worked for me: navbar[[4]][[1]][[1]]$children[[1]]$children[[2]]

Comment: @MalditoBarbudo Thank you for your comment. When using your code snippet, the search input is in the navbarPage() row, but tab 1 and tab 2 are hidden. Any ideas on what I can do?

Answer (score 2):

This is one possible way, to reconstruct the menu with HTML. It does not look very clean but it does what you are looking for.

app.R

```
library(shiny)

    ui <- shinyUI(
            tagList(
                    bootstrapPage(
                    HTML('
                         <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
                            <div class="navbar-header">
                                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                    </button>
                                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Old Faithful Geyser Data</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                                            <li class="active"><a href="#plot1" data-toggle="tab" data-value="Plot1">First</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#plot2" data-toggle="tab" data-value="Plot2">Second</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                                            <form class="navbar-form" role="search">
                                                    <div class="input-group">
                                                            <input id="searchBox" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="q">
                                                    </div>
                                            </form>
                                    </div>
                            </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
                         </nav>
                         '),
                    tags$div(class="container-fluid", 
                             tags$div(class="tab-content",
                                      HTML('<div class="tab-pane active" data-value="Plot1" id="plot1">'),
                                      sliderInput("bins1",
                                                  "Number of bins:",
                                                  min = 1,
                                                  max = 50,
                                                  value = 30),
                                      plotOutput("distPlot1"),
                                      verbatimTextOutput("searchBoxValuePlot1"),
                                      HTML('</div>'),
                                      HTML('<div class="tab-pane" data-value="Plot2" id="plot2">'),
                                      sliderInput("bins2",
                                                  "Number of bins:",
                                                  min = 1,
                                                  max = 50,
                                                  value = 30),
                                      plotOutput("distPlot2"),
                                      verbatimTextOutput("searchBoxValuePlot2"),                                  
                                      HTML('</div>')

                             )

                    )
            )
            ))

    server <- function(input, output, session) {
            output$distPlot1 <- renderPlot({

                    # generate bins based on input$bins from ui.R
                    x    <- faithful[, 2]
                    bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins1 + 1)

                    # draw the histogram with the specified number of bins
                    hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')

            })
            output$distPlot2 <- renderPlot({

                    # generate bins based on input$bins from ui.R
                    x    <- faithful[, 1]
                    bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins2 + 1)

                    # draw the histogram with the specified number of bins
                    hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')

            })
            searchBoxValue <- reactive({
                    input$searchBox
            })
            output$searchBoxValuePlot1 <- renderPrint({
                    paste("You entered: ", searchBoxValue(), "and you are on the first link", sep = " ")
            })
            output$searchBoxValuePlot2 <- renderPrint({
                    paste("You entered: ", searchBoxValue(), "and you are on the second link", sep = " ")
            })
    }

    shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Hi @Valter your solution stills amazing! But do you know if today we have a more clean soluion than this one?

Comment: Hi @JohnBonesJohnBones I would suggest to take a look at bslib: "The bslib R package provides a modern UI toolkit for Shiny and R Markdown based on Bootstrap" More specifically take a look at this: https://rstudio.github.io/bslib/reference/page_navbar.html. You should be able to include any standard Bootstrap element including the search box.

Comment: thannks for your time! Done it with `nav_item`! Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

In base Shiny you can do it using a `tabPanel`, if the re-rendering of current tabPanel is not to costly:

```
ui <- navbarPage('test',id='test',
                 tabPanel('my app1',
                          titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data1"),
                          sidebarLayout(
                            sidebarPanel(
                              sliderInput("bins",
                                          "Number of bins:",
                                          min = 1,
                                          max = 50,
                                          value = 30)),
                            mainPanel(plotOutput("distPlot1")))),
                 tabPanel('my app2',
                          titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data2"),
                          sidebarLayout(
                            sidebarPanel(
                              sliderInput("bins",
                                          "Number of bins:",
                                          min = 1,
                                          max = 50,
                                          value = 30)),
                            mainPanel(plotOutput("distPlot2")))),
                 tabPanel( value= "search_panel",
                           textInput("search", label=NULL, value="Search"))
                )

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observe({
    if(!is.null(input$test)){
      if(input$test=="search_panel")     # Go back to last active panel
        updateNavbarPage(session, 'test', selected = selected_panel)
      else                               # Save active panel
        selected_panel <<- input$test
      }
    })
  searchtext <- reactive({
    if(!is.null(input$search))
       if(input$search!="Search")
         return(input$search)
    return(NULL)
    })
  output$distPlot1 <- renderPlot({
    x    <- faithful[, 2]
    bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)
    hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white', 
         main=ifelse(is.null(searchtext()), "Alt title 1", searchtext()))
    })
  output$distPlot2 <- renderPlot({
    x    <- faithful[, 2]
    bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)
    hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white', 
         main=ifelse(is.null(searchtext()), "Alt title 2", searchtext()))
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```